# How to give background to Bootstrap columns without left and right padding?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I have this Bootstrap column structure:

```
.container>.row>.col-md-6*2
```

Problem is, that i want those two columns to have white backgrounds, but the background goes 15 pixels left and right OVER container and row.
Here is the image what I want to achieve:

[image: Where the red rectnagles are, i want to have white background.]
Where the red rectnagles are, i want to have white background.

Here is also JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tmdnd9g5/

Comment: Please provide us with your code that you have for us to help you out.

Comment: Here is the JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tmdnd9g5/

Comment: See my answer, let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a custom class and apply it to those elements and set

```
{margin:0;}
```

or else apply a custom class to the .row element and set the background to white

Answer (score 0):

Usually what I do is make a custom class and just add it to the element:

```
.col-no-pad {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Then add to the element's class attribute:

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-no-pad">
    Stuff
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the background to the row instead.

```
.row {
    background-color:#fff;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uu38zjct/

Comment: Why did I get a down vote? My solution works, provides code, and has a link to an example...